# ORA-00902: invalid datatype trying to define a column with a unique constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, types, oracle10g

I created the following table definition in netbeans ide 8.

```
CREATE TABLE DOCTOR_INFO(
DOCTOR_ID NUMBER(38) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DOCTORINFO_ID_UQ UNIQUE,
D_F_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
D_M_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
D_S_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
DOCTOR_NAME VARCHAR(50),
D_TITLE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
D_ACTIVE_STATUS BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
SUFFIX VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PASSWORD VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
SPECIALITY VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
QUALIFICATION_YEAR NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
UNIVERSITY_NAME VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
HOSPITAL_NAME VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
D_ADDR1 VARCHAR(50),
D_ADDR2 VARCHAR(50),
USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
D_CITY VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
D_STATE VARCHAR(50),
D_ZIPCODE NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
D_HOMEPHONE NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
D_WORKPHONE NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
D_MOBILE NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
START_DAYTIME TIMESTAMP,
END_DAYTIME TIMESTAMP,
START_NIGHTTIME TIMESTAMP,
END_NIGHTTIME TIMESTAMP,
D_TOKENLIMIT NUMBER(4),
D_DOB DATE NOT NULL
);
```

When I try to run it in Oracle 10g, I get this error:

> Error code 902, SQL state 42000: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
>   Line 1, column 1

What is wrong with the table definition?

Answer (score 1):

Your definition for column `DOCTOR_ID` does not conform to Oracle SQL syntax.  You cannot append a named constraint to a column declaration as you attempt to do.  You may do this ...

```
DOCTOR_ID NUMBER(38) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT DOCTORINFO_ID_UQ UNIQUE (DOCTOR_ID),
```

... to achieve the effect you seem to want.  If you don't care about the specific constraint name, however, then you can also do this:

```
DOCTOR_ID NUMBER(38) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
```